# How to add xib file when iam creating customcell in iphone application

Tags: ios6

How to add xib file when iam creating customcell in ios application.when iam trying behind hide in the xib check box ?

Comment: can u elaborate ur issues

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `objective-c class` like that :

[image]

Second, create a new `user interface` with the same name of your `objective-c class` like that :

[image]

finally fill the `Class item` of your view with the name of your `objective-c class` :

[image]

Enjoy